Conflicts in normality assesment
I have a small dataset (n=11) and when I do an assessment of normal distribution, I encounter this issue:

skewness and kurtosis is between (+2, -2)
shapiro - wilk p>0,05, indicating normality

However, the histogram and Q-Q plot graphs are telling me that the data is'not distributing normal.
I am planning to an wilxocon ranked-signed test or t-test according to distribution. I've checked both results, one resulting with p>0,05 and other <0,05 respectfully, which totaly changes the result.
In some sources; there is and general discussed rule that when sample size is < 30i the data should be assumed as non-normaly distributed.
So in my issue, how should I conclude, normal or non-normal distribution?

11 observations is'nt really enough for a normality test!

What are you measuring? What prior data are there for the distribution of that variable (in other, prior, experiments)?

Failing to reject the null doesn't mean the null is true. Sample size is small. Power is low. You almost certainly don't have normality. The question is how consequential is it for your purposes?. The test doesn't tell you that... it doesn't even know what your purposes are

"In some sources; there is and general discussed rule that when sample size is < 30 the data should be assumed as non-normaly distributed." ... this statement doesn't really make sense as it stands. Can you point to one of the sources that actually says it? ... I'm hoping they say something slightly different (albeit it's likely still not correct)

This two-step approach, first testing for normality and then choosing your later analysis based on that first test, isn't even a good idea with a large sample. See this page for discussion. One can further argue that normality testing is essentially useless. With small samples like yours there's no power to detect a deviation from normality, and with large-enough samples there will typically be a "statistically significant" deviation.

(Cohen ve Manion, 1994, s.90) stated that; for a data set to exhibit normal distribution properties, a sample size of over 30 is required. I've read this issue in some books too.

To begin with, it would be nice to know if are comparing 2 paired samples, each with 11 units, or just testing a single sample. Moving forward, I will assume a single sample.
Second, Wilcoxon signed-rank test (WSRt) and t-test (Tt) do not test the same thing. So it is very possible for 1 to be significant while the other is not. As everybody knows, the single sample Tt compares the mean of the sample to a hypothesized mean. The WSRt on the other hands compares the pseudomedian (see here) of the sample to a hypothesized pseudomedian. If, and only if, the sample comes from a symmetric distribution, then the WSRt compares the median (which now is also the mean), to a hypothesized median/mean.
So, if you care about the pseudo-median, use WSRt. But I seriously doubt that this is what you care about, nor what your audience will care about, let alone even understand.
So now, you are left to test the mean (Tt), or the true median (WSRt), one relying on normality (which Shapiro-Wilk told you was "not implausible"), or symmetry, which is not easily testable... (some would say the WSRt is a better test of symmetry that it is a test of the median...).
Now, you are worried that the Q-Q plot and the histogram look "not normal". Just for fun, using whatever software you have, draw a sample of size 11 out of $N(0,1)$. This is the histogram I got,. Pretty ugly is it not?. With sample size 11, do not try to eyeball normality; histogram and/or Q/Q plot will look pretty "ugly".
Bottom line; use a t-test if Shapiro-Wilk said it is "close enough" (and ignore the histogram; the Shapiro-Wilk test came from the Q-Q plot...). Even if the data is not really coming from a normal distribution, your result will not be horribly wrong. But if the data is not coming from a symmetric distribution, who knows where the real pseudo-median is? (and who cares?).
